# What is a word for a gap that is too large to close?

Tags: word-choice

What is a word for a gap that is too large to close?

I don't like ***insurmountable*** because that is a mountain and ***impassable*** just doesn't do it for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: ...unbridgeable

Comment: ..."a bridge too far".

Answer (score 4):

It might be described as a ***chasm*** or ***chasmal*** / ***chasmic***:

> **chasm**
>   *noun*
>
> 1. a yawning fissure or deep cleft in the earth's surface; gorge.
> 2. a breach or wide fissure in a wall or other structure.
> 3. a marked interruption of continuity; gap: a chasm in time.
> 4. a sundering breach in relations, as a divergence of opinions, beliefs, etc., between persons or groups
>
> *Related forms*
>   **chas·mal**, **chas·mic**, *adjective*
>
> -- Definition from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chasm)

Or possibly as an ***abyss*** or ***abyssal***

> **a·byss**
>   *noun*
>
> 1. a deep, immeasurable space, gulf, or cavity; vast chasm.
> 2. anything profound, unfathomable, or infinite: the abyss of time.
> 3. 1. the primal chaos before Creation.
>    2. the infernal regions; hell.
>    3. a subterranean ocean.
>
> -- Definition from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abyss)

Or if you're referring to a gap that's more metaphorical than literal, perhaps it could be described as a ***schism*** (I know of no adjective form)

> **schism**
>   *noun*
>
> 1. division or disunion, especially into mutually opposed parties.
> 2. the parties so formed.
> 3. *Ecclesiastical*.
>
>    1. a formal division within, or separation from, a church or religious body over some doctrinal difference.
>    2. the state of a sect or body formed by such division.
>    3. the offense of causing or seeking to cause such a division.
>
> -- Definition from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/schism)

Comment: Great answer +1 - and incidentally, I found occurrences of "schismically" when I Googled it - although Google tried very hard to steer me to "seismically".  lol!

Comment: @KristinaLopez Thanks, I figured there was some adjective form, and *schismic* makes sense, but I couldn't find any reference for it.

Comment: There's [_schismatic_](http://thesaurus.com/browse/schismatic?s=b). It's also a noun, but it's a synonym for _heretical_,  _nonconformist_, & _renegade_. And [_abysmal_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/abysmal) {[also](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abysmal&searchmode=none)}.

Comment: This is only a "great answer" if you totally ignore the spirit of the question.  OP doesn't want a replacement for the word *gap* that simply means "really, really big gap".  What they are after is an adjective to replace "really, really big", and they're going to stick with *gap* as their noun.  Actually, the best word contained within this answer is probably **yawning**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're even talking about *closing* the gap, then the most direct word that fits your use is simply **unclosable**.  Next after that (and perhaps more applicable to typical gaps) would be Edwin's **unbridgeable**.

I should mention that some (particularly Java programmers) might be inclined to spell *unclosable* as **uncloseable**.

Answer (score -1):

A great gulf.  See various versions of the Gospel of Luke, chapter 16, verse 26.  For example, the King James Version (KJV):

> And beside all this, between us and you there is a great gulf fixed : so that they which would pass from hence to you cannot ; neither can they pass to us, that would come from thence.